# Load balancer haproxy

Tags: web-application, web

can i configure a load balancer between two nodes by using only two ip adresses. I mean one of the two server will be a load balancer and backend server in the same time

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes. HAproxy doesn't prevent other programs running on the server.

Do understand that there are at least two downsides to this approach:

1. It reduces the effectiveness of the LB because the LB is serving
   additional programs. Arguably you could configure the LB with more
   CPU/RAM/IOPS to compensate - but that's extra cost.
2. The idea of a load balancer / HA proxy (not the same concepts,
   though the tech overlaps) is to have at least two FEs behind it.
   Both to handle load as well as to handle failures. Again,
   theoretically, you could have both FE and BE on the same node as the
   Load Balancer - but that only reduces the application robustness as
   well as security (an attacker wouldn't need additional effort to get
   to the BE if the LB is compromised).

In the end, it is not only  saving-one-IP-address vs design weakness, but also the additional cost of compensating the LB configuration & the additional effort to secure.